# ¿Como hacer para que un elemento no se cree validando una condicional con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, li

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es que si un promedio sobrepasa la nota de 10 que le muestre un cartel de precaucion, hasta ahi va bien pero al mismo tiempo que me muestra el cartel me imprime en el dom la nota cosa que eso deberia pasar si la nota es del 1 al 10, como podria hacer para que no se escriba en el dom si sobrepasa el 10? Abajo dejo el codigo de lo que tengo hasta ahora.

```
btnTotal.onclick = function realizarPromedio(){
    const aprobado = 7
    const mayor = 11
    nombreAlumno = document.getElementById('nom').value
    let nota1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num1').value)
    let nota2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num2').value)
    let nota3 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num3').value)
    resultadoNota = Math.round((nota1 + nota2 + nota3) / 3)

    if(resultadoNota >= aprobado){
        console.log("Nota final de " + nombreAlumno + " es " + resultadoNota + " esta aprobado" )
        swal({
            title: "Bien hecho!",
            text: nombreAlumno + " tu nota es " + resultadoNota + ", estas aprobado!",
            icon: "success",
        });
        baseDatos.push("Nombre: " + nombreAlumno + ", Promedio: " + resultadoNota )
    }else{
        console.log("Nota final de " + nombreAlumno + " es " + resultadoNota + " esta desaprobado" )
        swal({
            title: "Sigue Intentando",
            text: nombreAlumno + " tu nota es " + resultadoNota + ", estas desaprobado!",
            icon: "error",
        });
        baseDatos.push("Nombre: " + nombreAlumno + ", Promedio: " + resultadoNota )
        }

    const texto = "Nombre: " + nombreAlumno + ", Promedio: " + resultadoNota

    baseDatos.push(texto)

    const resultado = document.createElement("li")
    resultado.innerHTML = texto
    divPromedio.appendChild(resultado)

    if(resultadoNota >= mayor){
        swal({
            title: "Ingrese nuevamente una nota",
            text: "La nota tiene que ser numeros entre el 1 al 10, intentalo nuevamente!",
            icon: "warning",
        })
    }
    
    localStorage.setItem("Promedios", JSON.stringify(baseDatos)) 
}
´´´
```

Comment: Encadena el último `if` como parte de la comprobación de la nota.

Comment: Claro, intente hacerlo poniendo un if else y me sigue mostrando el promedio en el dom, como dirias de encadenarlo en la primera comprobacion?

Comment: `if(resultadoNota >= mayor){ ... } else if(resultadoNota < mayor && resultadoNota >= aprobado){ ... } else { ... }`